# Access dictionary values within a user-defined object and add them to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if there is a way to access specific dictionary values within user-defined objects?

E.g.

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c

test1=Test("text", 0, {"key1":0, "key2":1})
```

When doing

```
test1.c
```

I get:

> {'key1': 0, 'key2': 1}

But how can I get the dictionary value of, lets say, "key1" (only "key1")?

Also, I am trying to add the content of an object to a list (as specific list elements). Is that somehow possible?

I am trying to do something like:

```
test1_list=[]
test1_list=[].append(Test("text", 0, {"key1":0, "key2":1}))
```

When I do:

```
print(test1_list)
```

I only get:

> None

instead of:

> ["text", 0, {"key1":0, "key2":1}]

Comment: `test1.c['key1']`. You should review introductionary material like the Python tutorial.

Comment: So in your second question do you want to add the `test1` object or the content of the fields of `test1`?

Comment: I want to add the content of the fields of "test1" to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will make sense to have a closer look at [the python data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). **Your should be able to solve your issues yourself after reading through this documentation.**

At least it will help you to better understand the solutions below.

---

In short, here is how you get the value for a key:

```
test1.c['key1']
Out[5]: 0
```

And how to append to a list:

```
test1_list = []
test1_list.append(Test("text", 0, {"key1":0, "key2":1}))
```

or in one go:

```
test1_list = [Test("text", 0, {"key1":0, "key2":1})]
```

Comment: oh... thank you so much... I will definitely go trough the website you suggested.

Comment: My pleasure! And I wish you all the best on your coding adventures!

Comment: just one more thing.... when I do ">>> test1_list" I get:
[<__main__.Test object at 0x000001EF6CFDA630>], but not the content in form of list elements

Comment: @KideW This is normal, as python does not know a priory how to 'show' you the object you have put in the list. You can define the `__repr__` method for your class to tell python how to display your object. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__

Answer (score 0):

> But how can I get the dictionary value of, lets say, "key1" (only "key1")?

Here is a horrible (but, working and dynamic) answer using exec:

```
In [1]: class Test(object):
            def __init__(self, a, b, c):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b
            self.c = c
            try:
                self.__set_key_values()
            except ValueError:
                pass

            def __set_key_values(self):
                n = 1
                for k in self.c.keys():
                    exec(f'self.key{n} = {self.c[k]}')
                    n += 1
```

Instance your class with arguments:

```
In [2]: test1 = Test("text", 0, {"key1":0, "key2":1})
```

Try returning key values via direct access:

```
In [3]: test1.key1
Out [3]: 0

In [4]: test1.key2
Out [4]: 1
```